# Embedding many small movies in page (gif vs mp4 vs webm vs ?)

Tags: performance, video, ffmpeg, gif, animated-gif

I am making a webpage which will contain around 20-25 small-resolution (~56x56) and short-length (~3 sec) movies which will be set to autoplay and loop, so they will be looping on the page at all times. They are mostly dispersed throughout the page, so cannot easily be merged into bigger movies.

I'm trying to decide on the right format to use, balancing filesize, quality, and processor overhead.

mp4 seems the best option in terms of quality and filesize, however embedding many small mp4s on the page felt to me slow and made my computer get hot. Despite the fact that if they were one mp4, it would be only around 300x240 -- it seems there is a lot of CPU overhead if they are divided.

gif is lower quality *and* bigger filesize, but the CPU performance felt smoother. I can't prove it though because I didn't measure it -- are gif's known to be better performance than mp4?

I have not tried other formats (webm, avi, ogg, etc) but I am unsure of how supported all of these formats are by most browsers and I want the webpage to be viewable from multiple browsers/countries.

How can I determine the best format to use for these videos?  Is there a tool which can measure the CPU performance of my webpage so I can quantify the performance issues?

Answer (score 3):

Playing many videos on a single page is a problem for most OS's as video decoding and playback is CPU intensive.

Some systems will also have hardware elements (HW acceleration) in the video playback 'pipeline' (the series of functions the OS, browser and player perform to unpack, decode, prepare and display the video) and these elements may not support or have limited capacity for parallel playbacks.

There is a fairly common workaround to this scenario if you know in advance what videos you want to play on the page, and if you don't have too many different video combinations for different users etc: this is to combine the videos on the server side into a single video. This means the users still sees what looks like multiple videos but you are doing all the heavy lifting on the server side.

The drawback is that you can't start or stop individual videos or quickly change the mix of videos.

If you plan to support mobile browsers also you should be aware that most mobile devices do not support Autoplay (to help conserve users bandwidth), and smaller devices such as phones often do not support inline video (the video will always play full screen). [**Update Feb 2017**: mobile devices are beginning to support autoplay as mobile data rates increase, and most will now support inline, with iOS adding this in iOS 10]